# NestJs REPL Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Tags: nestjs

When using NestJS REPL I'm getting the following error despite running against an async function that I can see is returning a Promise.
`Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

See the block below for the Service code I'm calling and an example of the code returning a promise but then throwing the error when trying to await.

```
CoffeesService.ts
  async findOne(id: string) {
    const coffee = await this.coffeeRepository.findOne(id, {
      relations: ['flavors'],
    });

    if (!coffee) {
      throw new NotFoundException(`Coffee ${id} not found`);
    }
    return coffee;
  }
```

```
REPL

> coffeesService.findOne(1)
Promise {
  <pending>,
  [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 393,
  [Symbol(trigger_async_id_symbol)]: 45,
  [Symbol(destroyed)]: { destroyed: false }
}

> await coffeesService.findOne(1)
await coffeesService.findOne(1)
^^^^^

Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

According to NestJS docs, await is a top level function [https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/repl#:~:text=Native%20functions-,Read%2DEval%2DPrint%2DLoop%20(REPL),%7D%0A%3E%20await%20appController.getHello()%0A%27Hello%20World!%27,-To%20display%20all](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/repl#:%7E:text=Native%20functions-,Read%2DEval%2DPrint%2DLoop%20(REPL),%7D%0A%3E%20await%20appController.getHello()%0A%27Hello%20World!%27,-To%20display%20all)

This is a great new feature and I'm hoping I'm just doing something wrong :/

Comment: which version of node are you using?

Comment: that's probably a misleading in the docs site. You cannot use `await` like that unless you're using node16, I believe. I just tested and it worked.

Comment: You're exactly right, I was on node 14. Upgraded to 18 and work like a charm! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

As suggested above, I needed to upgrade past node version 16. it works perfectly in node 18

```
> await get(CoffeesService).findOne(1)
Coffee {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Hobo roast',
  brand: 'SF Roasters',
  description: null,
  recommendations: 0,
  flavors: [
    Flavor { id: 1, name: 'trash' },
    Flavor { id: 2, name: 'cigarettes' }
  ]
}
```